# Is it possible to ingest work items from Devops into SQL synapse using a data factory

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

We want to pull the work items from devops into our sql synapse database and then do some reporting on them using power bi. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own? What hasn't worked? What resources have you used to see if it's possible?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible, follow this [**article**](https://www.techtalkcorner.com/enable-azure-devops-azure-synapse-analytics/) it has a detailed explanation about how to ingest work items from ***DevOps*** into ***azure synapse*** using a data factory.

If you want to connect with the ***Azure synapse*** to ***power bi*** please follow this:

Go to ***manage*** -> ***linked service*** ->Click ***+ New*** -> Search and click **Power BI** and click **Continue** -> Enter a name for the ***linked service*** and select a ***workspace*** .
[image: Ref2]

[image: Ref3]

[image: Ref4]

Expand ***Power BI*** and the ***workspace*** and you can use.

[image: Ref5]

**Reference:**

https://www.techtalkcorner.com/enable-azure-devops-azure-synapse-analytics/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/quickstart-power-bi

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure that's what I'm after. The url links to a document on how to link the codebase into devops which we've already done and we have code builds and release pipelines already setup. I want to connect to devops through the data factory and ingest the work items (epics, pbis, features, tasks etc) as my management team want some reports in pbi around this. I know there is a connection you can make through power bi to ingest the work items directly into power bi but I want to ingest them into the synapse database first.